# Will A=A+B allocate new memory?

Tags: matlab, memory-management

When writing

```
A = A + B;
```

A and B beeing matrices, will MATLAB perform this "in-place" i.e. change the elements in A, or will new memory be allocated to store the result? If so, how do I avoid that?

The reason I wonder is that if, for example, one writes

```
A = A + B + A^2;
```

The original data needs to be accessed multiple times and thus cannot simply be overwritten by the first addition.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "thus cannot simply be overwritten by the first addition."? Can you elaborate?

Comment: `A+B` is an element-wise operation so the MATLAB just-in-time engine can re-use `A` to hold the result. In the second case `A^2` is a matrix multiplication and to calculate a single element requires access to an entire row and column of `A`. Basically it needs access to the original `A` which means we can't expect to do everything in place. In general it's difficult to guess what MATLAB is doing at this level as it is intentionally not documented (partly because it can change with releases and in some sense it's against the spirit of the language to work with low-level implementation details).

Comment: Do you mean A = A + B + A.^2 ?

Comment: @marc: no, not element-wise multiplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tested it on my computer using the system monitor. I observe that `A=A+B` does not allocate new memory, but `A=A+B+A^2` does allocate new memory.

That makes sense since in C++ , it's easy to write the first code without memory allocation, but it's not possible for the second code.